# Meaning for 三日後に　本気出せ

Tags: meaning, translation

From what I understand, it means "Do your best three days after the fact"? But it doesn't make much sense in English

Here is the line that precedes, if it is any help:

> テストも授業も却下可能
> 三日後に　本気出せ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where did "after the fact" come from? 三日後に just means "three days later", and 三日後に本気出せ means "Get serious three days later", which implies "It's not time to get serious now, worry later".

Comment: Thanks for this. I had always thought this meant something along the lines of 'knowledge settles in the brain after three days': as in if you just learn something, there is no point in assessing it just yet as you will not yet have had a chance to properly learn this.